# Sending PostMessage WM_KEYDOWN/UP to notepad edit control works with VK_F5 but not with an ordinary letter

Tags: vba, winapi, keyboard-events

I am trying to send WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP to notepad's edit control. The following example works, if I send a `VK_F5`: Notepad inserts the current date and time. However, If I try to send a simple `h`, notepad doesn't stop inserting one `h` after another so that I have to kill notepad with the task manager.

I don't understand why it works with one key and not with the other and I'd like to know what I have to change to send a simple letter.

```
option explicit

const WM_KEYDOWN     = &h0100
const WM_KEYUP       = &h0101
const VK_F5          = &h074

declare function FindWindow          lib "user32"  alias "FindWindowA" ( _
     byVal lpClassName  as string, _
     byVal lpWindowName as string) as long

declare function FindWindowEx        lib "user32"  alias "FindWindowExA"      ( _
     byVal hWnd           as long  , _
     byVal hWndChildAfter as long  , _
     byVal lpClassName    as string, _
     byVal lpWindowName   as string) as long

declare function MapVirtualKey       lib "user32"       alias "MapVirtualKeyA"        ( _
     byVal wCode          as long,   _
     byVal wMapType       as long) as long

declare function PostMessage         lib "user32"       alias "PostMessageA" ( _
     byVal hwnd   as long, _
     byVal wMsg   as long, _
     byVal wParam as long, _
           lParam as any) as long

declare function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll"         alias "ShellExecuteA"     ( _
     byVal hwnd         as long  , _
     byVal lpOperation  as string, _
     byVal lpFile       as string, _
     byVal lpParameters as string, _
     byVal lpDirectory  as string, _
     byval lpShowCmd    as long)      as long

declare sub      Sleep               lib "kernel32" (byVal dwMilliseconds as long   )

sub main()

    dim hWndNotepad     as long
    dim hWndNotepadEdit as long

  '
  ' Start notepad
  '
    ShellExecute 0, "Open", "notepad.exe", "", "", 1
  '
  ' Find the window handle for notepad
  '
    hWndNotepad = FindWindow("notepad", vbNullString)
    while hWndNotepad = 0
    '
    ' Wait a while if notepad window not yet initialized:
    '
      Sleep 100 
      hWndNotepad = FindWindow("notepad", vbNullString)
    wend

  '
  ' Find the window handle of the edit control
  ' in notepad:
  '
    hWndNotepadEdit = FindWindowEx(hWndNotepad, 0, "Edit", vbNullString)

    dim vkCode as long
  ' This works:
  ' ----------
  '
  ' vkCode = VK_F5
  '
  ' This doesn't:
  ' ------------
    vkCode = asc("H")

    dim lParam as long
    lParam = 1 + MapVirtualKey(vkCode, 0) * 2^16

    PostMessage hWndNotepadEdit, WM_KEYDOWN, vkCode, lParam
    Sleep 100
    PostMessage hWndNotepadEdit, WM_KEYUP  , vkCode, lParam or &hc0000000

end sub
```

Comment: For 64 bit users you will need to add PtrSafe and alter lParam = 1 + MapVirtualKey(vkCode, 0) * 2^16 to this line lParam = 1 + MapVirtualKey(vkCode, 0) * 2 ^ 16. So compiler is not confused as to operator versus operand value as LongLong

Comment: A better way to send keystrokes to another application is to use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).  I would at least take a look to see if you can make this work for you (debt repaid, @II).

Comment: Will this not ever end? [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: No. It will not ever end.

Comment: This question is not about "reliably simulating keyboard input", rather, the question is why sending VK_F5 works and sending `asc('H')` doesn't.

Comment: If that *is* the question, then I'm sure you'll find valuable information in this blog entry: [Why doesn’t my keyboard hook get called for keyboard messages I manually posted?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150925-00/?p=91511) Also worth reading to understand other failure modes: [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903). Although I fail to understand, why an answer to that question is any more useful than suggesting to use a strategy that *can* be made to work reliably.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in declaration of PostMessage function (lParam as Any)
Correct is ByVal lParam as Long

```
Option Explicit

Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
Const WM_CHAR = &H102
Const WM_KEYUP = &H101
Const VK_F5 = &H74

Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
     ByVal lpClassName As String, _
     ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" ( _
     ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal hWndChildAfter As Long, _
     ByVal lpClassName As String, _
     ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Declare Function MapVirtualKey Lib "user32" Alias "MapVirtualKeyA" ( _
     ByVal wCode As Long, _
     ByVal wMapType As Long) As Long

Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" ( _
     ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal wMsg As Long, _
     ByVal wParam As Long, _
     ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
     ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal lpOperation As String, _
     ByVal lpFile As String, _
     ByVal lpParameters As String, _
     ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
     ByVal lpShowCmd As Long) As Long

Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub main()

    Dim hWndNotepad     As Long
    Dim hWndNotepadEdit As Long

  '
  ' Start notepad
  '
    ShellExecute 0, "Open", "notepad.exe", "", "", 1
  '
  ' Find the window handle for notepad
  '
    hWndNotepad = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Bez názvu – Poznámkový blok")
    While hWndNotepad = 0
    '
    ' Wait a while if notepad window not yet initialized:
    '
      Sleep 100
      hWndNotepad = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Bez názvu – Poznámkový blok")
    Wend

  '
  ' Find the window handle of the edit control
  ' in notepad:
  '
    hWndNotepadEdit = FindWindowEx(hWndNotepad, 0, "Edit", vbNullString)

    Dim vkCode As Long
  ' This works:
  ' ----------
  '
  ' vkCode = VK_F5
  '
  ' This doesn't:
  ' ------------
    vkCode = Asc("H")

    Dim lParam As Long
    lParam = 1 + MapVirtualKey(vkCode, 0) * (2 ^ 16)
    Debug.Print Hex(vkCode), Hex(lParam)

    PostMessage hWndNotepadEdit, WM_KEYDOWN, vkCode, lParam  
'    PostMessage hWndNotepadEdit, WM_KEYUP, vkCode, lParam Or &HC0000000

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send simple letters as well as other characters in hex format. For simple `h` it is `Const VK_H = &H48`. Some other examples:

```
Const VK_NUMPAD0 = &H60
Const VK_NUMPAD1 = &H61
Const VK_NUMPAD2 = &H62
```

> VK_A thru VK_Z are the same as their ASCII equivalents: 'A' thru 'Z'
>
> VK_0 thru VK_9 are the same as their ASCII equivalents: '0' thru '9'

Source [WIN32_API](https://www.aeternus.sg/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Win32API_PtrSafe.txt).

If I understand correctly, problem is that the numbers do not always match the "real" hex numbers for ASCII.